# Bootstrap problems in Firefox and IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have built a blog using WordPress and Twitter Bootstrap. Now, I am testing it in various browsers. It seems that the navbar dropdowns are not working in Firefox and IE. They work fine in Chrome and Opera and Chrome for Android. I am unable to find the reason and solution for this problem. There are no console errors as well. The link is http://goo.gl/5bwZUA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was due to `display: block` in the css file. I removed that and everything works perfectly now.